# Join in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, associations

I have 6 tables in the database: CarMaster, Audi, Toyota, Tata, Hyundai, Ford, Mapping

Mapping table has two columns: mapId, tableName

Entry in Mapping table will be like "1, Audi", "2, Toyota" and so on till "5, Ford"

Primary key in first five tables is carId.

Also, the CarMaster has a mapId column which on join with Mapping table will give the table name. This could then be used to join carId key with the corresponding table so that further details about the car could be fetched.

For e.g. say carId is 10 with mapId 3. mapId 3 means Tata. So further details on carId 10 will be present in Tata table and so CarMaster and Tata will be joined to fetch more details.

How to map this scenario in Hibernate ? What will be the associations between the six tables ?

I am listing the POJO below, so that someone could help me with association annotations quickly without much typing.

```
class CarMaster implements Serializable
 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private String carId;

    @Column(name = "map_id")
    private String mapId;

    //other columns

 } 

class Audi implements Serializable
 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private String carId;

    //other columns
 } 

class Toyota implements Serializable
 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private String carId;

    //other columns
 } 

class Tata implements Serializable
 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private String carId;

    //other columns
 } 

class Hyundai implements Serializable
 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private String carId;

    //other columns
 }

class Ford implements Serializable
 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private String carId;

    //other columns
 }

class Mapping implements Serializable
 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "map_id")
    private String mapId;

    @Column(name = "table_name")
    private String tableName;
 }
```

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: I do not know if it is just for the sake of making an example, but those table names points to a very bad design...

Comment: @SJuan76: Yes I know.. But unfortunately, I can not do much about it.. I have to work with this design..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have an entity inheritance tree using the joined subclass strategy. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-joinedsubclass

The only difference is that Hibernate doesn't need the `mapId` discriminator in `CarMaster`, and also doesn't need the `Mapping` table at all. So, if you really need to keep these in the database model, map the Mapping as a regular entity, and the `mapId` column in `CarMaster` as a `ManyToOne` association to `Mapping`. You'll just need to make sure that each time you create a Ford instance, you initialize its mapping association with the Mapping instance which has the "Ford" table name.

Comment: So many to one mapping between CarMaster and Mapping and inheritance mapping between CarMaster and remaining classes... and there will be four subClasses element inside CarMaster class element with key column as carId... will there be a CarMaster property in Audi, Tata, etc. which points to CarMaster ?

Comment: No: since you have an inheritance relationship between Ford and CarMaster, a Ford **is** a CarMaster. Ford extends CarMaster.

Comment: Thanks.. will check the solution and update the question with any difficulties!